# Secondary monitor not turning on after PC turned the screen off

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, windows-10-v1809

I've had this issue ever since updating to Windows 10 1809. My second monitor is connected to my PC via VGA and to my Nintendo Switch via HDMI. After my computer turns off the screen (`Settings > Power & Sleep > Screen`) and I turn them on again by moving the mouse, pressing a key, etc. the second monitor doesn't wake up.

Windows does "think" there are two monitors connected, so I'll still be able to move my cursor to the second, but doesn't seem to send any signal to the second one. I have to unplug either the VGA or the HDMI cable for the second monitor to give image again.

This monitor in question is a, now couple years old, [Philips 227ELH](https://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/227E3LHSU_00/led-monitor-with-smartimage-lite).

I haven't changed anything in the hardware between updating to 1809. My main monitor is connected through HDMI to the motherboard. I don't have a video card in my build, but am using the AMD Radeon internal graphics. That being said, no updates of those co-occured with the issue. Updating/Reinstalling video drivers also didn't work.

The obvious question here is if anyone knows how to fix this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar issue so I swapped my second screen to use DVI instead of VGA. I think this is due to DVI being able to carry a data signal. Are you able to test this? Can you also [edit] your question to include the make/model of the screen?

Comment: @Burgi I unfortunately cannot test this as I don't own a DVI cable. I have edited the question to include the model of the monitor. Personally I'd also not want to resort to a hardware fix for an issue that was caused by software, but maybe there aren't any other options.